# Titlesec commands creating "bookmarks" on file structure

Tags: titlesec, texstudio

I used the `titlesec` package to customize my sections. When I use the commands `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`, a "bookmark" is created because I wrote `\section` inside those commands, which according to the package documentation is necessary.

[image: Screenshot of TeXstudio interface]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.7em}{}[]
\titlespacing{\section}{0em}{1.5em}{1.5em}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I'm using TeXstudio and on the "Structure" menu on the left you can see the first two "bookmarks" (don't know the correct name for it) for the sections: `\normalfont\bfseries` and `0em`, corresponding to the first two `\section`s in the code. How can I use those commands without making those bookmarks?

Comment: TeXStudio should disable making structure bookmarks until seeing `\begin{document}`. Obfuscating code just to avoid this mishap is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fool TeXstudio into not seeing the `\section` inside `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`. For that use:

```
\expandafter\titleformat\expandafter{\csname section\endcsname}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.7em}{}[]
\expandafter\titlespacing\expandafter{\csname section\endcsname}{0em}{1.5em}{1.5em}
```

Comment: Other options should also exist; for example, using `\@nameuse{section}`.

Answer (score 0):

The structure making process of TeXStudio should be disabled between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` to begin with.

The following code is probably overkill for the particular application, but it can give ideas for renewing the management of options for `titlesec`.

The refurbishing proceeds this way:

1. If `\titleformat` or `\titlespacing` is called with a single token as argument, assume it is `\section` or other sectioning command name; the `*`-variant is taken into consideration.
2. If the argument to `\titlespacing` is not a single token, build a command name for it, because we assume it is `\titlespacing{section}` or similar; the `*`-variant is taken into consideration.
3. If the argument to `\titleformat` (no `*`) consists of more than one token, it can either be a single sectioning command name (without the backslash) or a set of key-value options.
4. In the previous case, if an unknown key is scanned, assume it is a sectioning command name such as `section`: pass `name=\section`.
5. The key `numberless` is passed as is.
6. A key-value pair such as `name=\section` is passed as is.
7. A key-value pair such as `name=section` passes `name=\section`.

In the last four cases, “passing” means calling the original `\titleformat` with the built argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,letltxmacro,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\LetLtxMacro \titlesectitleformat \titleformat
\LetLtxMacro \titlesectitlespacing \titlespacing

\RenewDocumentCommand{\titlespacing}{sm}
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl { #2 }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl { \exp_not:c { #2 } }
   }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \exp_args:NNV \titlesectitlespacing * \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl
   }
   {
    \exp_args:NV \titlesectitlespacing \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl
   }
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\titleformat}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_if_single:nTF { #2 }
     {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl { #2 }
     }
     {
      \tl_set:Nx \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl { \exp_not:c { #2 } }
     }
    \exp_args:NNV \titlesectitleformat * \l_xtitlesec_arg_tl
   }
   {\xtitlesec_titleformat:n { #2 }}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \xtitlesec_titleformat:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   {% the argument is just '\levelname'
    \titlesectitleformat { #1 }
   }
   {% otherwise scan the argument more carefully
    \clist_clear:N \l_xtitlesec_options_clist
    \keys_set:nn { xtitlesec/titleformat } { #1 }
    \exp_args:NV \titlesectitleformat \l_xtitlesec_options_clist
   }
 }

\clist_new:N \l_xtitlesec_options_clist

\keys_define:nn { xtitlesec/titleformat }
 {
  name .code:n = 
   \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
    {% the value is just one token, assume it is '\levelcommand'
     \clist_put_right:Nn \l_xtitlesec_options_clist { name=#1 }
    }
    {% the value is multitoken, assume it is 'levelcommand'
     \clist_put_right:Nx \l_xtitlesec_options_clist { name=\exp_not:c { #1 } }
    }
  ,
  numberless .code:n =
   \clist_put_right:Nn \l_xtitlesec_options_clist { numberless }
  ,
  unknown .code:n =
   \clist_put_right:Nx \l_xtitlesec_options_clist { name=\exp_not:c { \l_keys_key_tl } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% example calls follow

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.7em}{}[]
\titleformat{section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.7em}{}[]
\titleformat{name=section,numberless}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.7em}{}[]

\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{1.5em}{1.5em}
\titlespacing*{section}{0em}{1.5em}{1.5em}
```

Comment: I`m a beginner on TeX so the code really is overkill for my application. But i understood what you said with "Obfuscating code just to avoid this mishap is not the best solution". For now @Werner solution will do. Appreciate the help.